# modiying vold.fstab

Tags: internal-storage, external-sd

I have tried to swap phone storage to external storage by modiying vold.fstab.  After rebooting my Kata i3, I can't access phone storage, sd card and extnal usb storage.

Previous storage setting

```
 Internal storage - working with (1gb)
 Phone storage - working (13gb)
 SD CARD - working
 External USB Storage - working
```

After modifying vold.fstab:

```
 Internal Storage - working
 Phone Storage - not working/no access
 Sd Card - not working/no access
 External USB Storage - not working/ no access
```

Please help! Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you show us the `vold.fstab` before and after your changes?